# MultiByteToWideChar for Unicode code pages 1200, 1201, 12000, 12001

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, unicode

I have a function that converts strings from various encodings into Unicode-16 used internally by Windows. For that I used [MultiByteToWideChar](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd319072%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API. But I just discovered that the following:

```
//See how much data do we need?
//UNIT nCodePage = 1201;  // just as an example
UINT nchLen = ::MultiByteToWideChar(nCodePage, 0, 
    pByteArrayToConvert, ncbSzByteArrayToConvert, NULL, 0);
if(!nchLen)
{
    //Failed
}
```

fails for the following Unicode code pages with error code `ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER` (87):

```
> 1200  utf-16  Unicode UTF-16, little endian byte order
> 1201  unicodeFFFE Unicode UTF-16, big endian byte order
> 12000 utf-32  Unicode UTF-32, little endian byte order
> 12001 utf-32BE    Unicode UTF-32, big endian byte order
```

Any idea why and how to do those conversions?

Comment: Could it because those code pages are only available to managed applications? Source: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd317756(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: @RichardCritten: That link applies to Windows as a whole, not just for managed apps.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Windows does not support UTF-32 at all, you have to implement that manually.

`MultiByteToWideChar()` does not support conversions **from** UTF-16 or UTF-32.  On the other hand, for codepages 1200 and 1201, your input data is *already* in UTF-16.  `MultiByteToWideChar()` outputs UTF-16LE data, so for codepage 1200 just return the input data as-is, and for codepage 1201 simply swap the endian of each UTF-16 codeunit.  But for codepages 12000 and 12001, you will have to convert the data manually (or use a 3rd party library, or the STL's built-in UTF-16/32 conversions if you are using C++11 or later).

Try something like this:

```
UINT BytesToUTF16LE(UINT CodePage, LPCSTR lpMultiByteStr, int cbMultiByte, LPWSTR lpWideCharStr, int cchWideChar)
{
    UINT nchLen;

    switch (nCodePage)
    {
        case 1200: // UTF-16LE
        case 1201: // UTF-16BE
        {
            if ((!lpMultiByteStr) || (cbMultiByte < 0) || (cchWideChar < 0))
            {
                ::SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
                return 0;
            }

            cbMultiByte /= 2;
            nchLen = cbMultiByte;

            if (lpWideCharStr)
            {
                if (cchWideChar < nchLen)
                {
                    ::SetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
                    return 0;
                }

                if (nCodePage == 1200)
                    CopyMemory(lpWideCharStr, lpMultiByteStr, nchLen * 2);
                else
                {
                    UINT16 pCodeUnits = (UINT16) lpMultiByteStr;

                    for (int i = 0; i < cbMultiByte; ++i)
                    {
                        lpWideCharStr[i] = (WCHAR) (
                            ((pCodeUnits[i] << 8) & 0xFF00) |
                            ((pCodeUnits[i] >> 8) & 0x00FF)
                        );
                    }
                }
            }

            ::SetLastError(0);
            break;
        }

        case 12000: // UTF-32LE
        case 12001: // UTF-32BE
        {
            if ((!lpMultiByteStr) || (cbMultiByte < 0) || (cchWideChar < 0))
            {
                ::SetLastError(ERROR_INVALID_PARAMETER);
                return 0;
            }

            PUINT32 pCodePoints = (PUINT32) lpMultiByteStr;
            cbMultiByte /= 4;

            nchLen = 0;

            for(int i = 0; i < cbMultiByte; ++i)
            {
                UINT32 CodePoint = pCodePoints[i];
                if (nCodePage == 12001)
                {
                    CodePoint = (
                        ((CodePoint >> 24) & 0x000000FF) |
                        ((CodePoint >> 8 ) & 0x0000FF00) |
                        ((CodePoint << 8 ) & 0x00FF0000) |
                        ((CodePoint << 24) & 0xFF000000)
                    );
                }

                if (CodePoint < 0x10000)
                {
                    if (lpWideCharStr)
                    {
                        if (cchWideChar < 1)
                        {
                            ::SetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
                            return 0;
                        }

                        *lpWideCharStr++ = (WCHAR) (CodePoint & 0xFFFF);
                        --cchWideChar;
                    }

                    ++nchLen;
                }
                else if (CodePoint <= 0x10FFFF)
                {
                    if (lpWideCharStr)
                    {
                        if (cchWideChar < 2)
                        {
                            ::SetLastError(ERROR_INSUFFICIENT_BUFFER);
                            return 0;
                        }

                        CodePoint -= 0x10000;
                        *lpWideCharStr++ = (WCHAR) (0xD800 + ((CodePoint >> 10) & 0x3FF));
                        *lpWideCharStr++ = (WCHAR) (0xDC00 + (CodePoint & 0x3FF));
                        cchWideChar -= 2;
                    }

                    nchLen += 2;
                }
                else
                {
                    ::SetLastError(ERROR_NO_UNICODE_TRANSLATION);
                    return 0;
                }
            }

            ::SetLastError(0);
            break;
        }

        default:
            nchLen = ::MultiByteToWideChar(nCodePage, 0, lpMultiByteStr, cbMultiByte, lpWideCharStr, cchWideChar);
            break;
    }

    return nchLen;
}
```

Then you can do this:

```
UINT nchLen = BytesToUTF16LE(nCodePage, pByteArrayToConvert, ncbSzByteArrayToConvert, NULL, 0)
if ((!nchLen) && (GetLastError() != 0))
{
    //Failed
}
...
BytesToUTF16LE(nCodePage, pByteArrayToConvert, ncbSzByteArrayToConvert, ...)
```

Answer (score 1):

Those conversions are not served by `MultiByteToWideChar` because UTF-16 and UTF-32 are not MBCS encodings.

As for how to convert them, do it as follows:

- UTF-16LE, no conversion necessary.
- UTF-16BE, byte swap each 16 bit character element.
- UTF-32LE, convert each 32 bit character element to either one or two 16 bit character elements. The algorithm is described here: http://unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf16-3
- UTF-32BE, byte swap each 32 bit character element, and then treat as UTF-32LE.

You might consider using a library such as ICU.