# C++ How to get the std::wstring of a int value?

Tags: c++, type-conversion, integer, wstring

I have an `int val = 0x1234;` and want to get the `std::wstring` (ሴ)of that number

```
int val = 0x1234;
std::wstring wstr =  to_wstring(val) ( this gives me L"4660" which is not what I want !)
std::wstring wstr_OK =  ????         ( it should give me the character ሴ)
```

Comment: Might not be the most elegant way, but this should work: `wstr.resize(1);    wstr[0] = val;`.

Comment: `std::wstring(1, 0x1234)`?

Comment: std::bit_cast it to char32_t or directly to wchar_t

Comment: Or just `std::wstring{val}` since an `initializer_list` overload prevails over others.

Answer (score 1):

[`std::to_wstring`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_wstring) (as well as `std::to_string`) is creating a string representation of a value.
In case of an `int` it will create a string where each **digit** is converted into a character that **represent it**.
For example `1` will be represented as the character `'1'` (which has a different numeric value - e.g. 49 if this was ascii).

In your case you already know the numeric value of the desired character, so you can simply assign the element of your `wstring` with it:

```
std::wstring wstr;
wstr.resize(1);    
wstr[0] = val;
```

Or more simply:

```
std::wstring wstr(1, val);
```

**Note:**
The solution above assumes in general that the numeric value can be indeed stored in one `wstring` element, i.e. `wchar_t`. This seems to be the case for the specific code that you used (`0x1234`).
For more info see: [Convert unicode codepoint to utf-16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66679330/convert-unicode-codepoint-to-utf-16).

Comment: What if it takes more than a single `wchar_t` to represent the code point?

Comment: The OP seems to be right with the assumption that this specific code can be stored in a `wstring`. Do you think this is incorrect ?

Comment: Any code point can be stored in `wstring`, but some need surrogate pairs. This specific code point might not, but this answer is wrong in the general case. See the duplicate question.

Comment: I understand. Added a note.